# "Who doors wins"

Tags: meaning, idioms, expressions

What does this expression mean?

> [Who doors wins](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2548597/Red-faced-Turkish-special-forces-fail-smash-way-house-dawn-raid-end-having-knock-ask-come-in.html)

Is it an idiom? Or is it a typo? Apparently, it makes no sense.

Comment: Headlines are only supposed to attract your attention, not to stand as imperishable prose. In British tabloids, a weak pun is a very common attention-getting device.

Comment: Do we have some context?

Comment: Yes, but links sometimes cease to be available and we try to make these questions and answers have an enduring use. Usually at very least a full sentence, and often a paragraph is quoted in the question as well as the link.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mis-hearing of the well-known *who **dares** wins*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No, it's a Daily Mail headline. Much though I deplore it, the Mail is a legitimate source of English, and questions arising therefrom should not be closed.

Comment: @TimLymington: Okay, well it's a lame pun then. But given target the readership of the Mail, I think it's pretty much axiomatic that understanding the reference would be trivial for native speakers. And I don't really think ELU should be in the business of explaining such ephemeral usages to non-native speakers, so I stand by my closevote, if not the cited reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a pun on the motto of the [Special Air Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Air_Service) (part of the British Special Forces), "Who dares wins".

The article refers to the Turkish Special Forces, and ridicules their plight when compared to the British forces. As everyone knows — and especially the *Daily Mail* — the British forces are the best in the world<sup>1</sup>.

[image: Badge of the SAS]

<sup>1</sup> Yes, there is a touch of irony here, although it's probably true.

Answer (score 4):

It is a joke.

The idiom is

> Who dares, wins.

Meaning that you cannot expect to win anything if you do not dare to take any risks.

Because here a door is playing a crucial role in the news story, whoever created the headline thought it would be funny to combine the door with the verb "dare" - supposedly because they sound a bit similar.

This kind of word jokes are common in certain areas of the media. The jokes are more appreciated by some than by others, and the quality is not always considered to be very high.

Answer (score 0):

*groan* It's a bad pun (play of words), the original being "who *dares* wins". It's supposed to be funny (said the man from the Daily Mail.)

Comment: Actually, it's even funnier than you thought. See Andrew Leach on this page.

Comment: Yeah, I'm all for prescriptive humor.